# Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I currently try to upload a file to Firebase Storage. To do so, I created a simple Reactjs component:

```
export default function setProfilePhoto() {

    const [thumbnail, setThumbnail] = useState(null)
    const { user } = useAuthContext()
    

    const handleFileChange = (e) => {
      setThumbnail(null)
      let selectedFile = e.target.files[0]
      
      if (!selectedFile){
          console.log('No file selected')
          return
      }
      if (!selectedFile.type.includes('image')){
        console.log('File must be an image')
        return
      }
      if (selectedFile.size > 100000){
        console.log('File must be less than 100kb')
        return
      }
      setThumbnail(selectedFile)
      console.log("File selected: ", selectedFile);
      }

      const handleUploadFile = async () => {
        const uploadPath = `profilepictures/${user.uid}/${thumbnail.name}`
        const img = await projectStorage.ref(uploadPath).put(thumbnail)
      }

  return (
    <div>
        <input 
          required
          type="file"
          onChange={handleFileChange}
        />
        <button onClick={handleUploadFile}>upload</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

But after I try to upload the file, I get the following error:

```
FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'profilepictures/[user uid]/untitled.png'.
```

I already tried to play around a bit with the rules but even with no restrictions it doesn't allow me to upload the file. The Firestore rule I currently have is:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**}{
        allow read, write, create, delete;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing in the rules:

```
    allow read, write, create, delete : if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;;
```

This is not the best of security rules, but at least you understand if the problem is in that line

Comment: I get the same error. But with my current rule every request should be allowed. So the problem shouldn't be the auth. When I make the request, I already singed in the user.

Comment: Maybe you are modifying cloud.firestore rules instead of firebase.storage rules?

Comment: Yes, you were right. Somehow the service was wrong. In line two of my rule I had `service cloud.firestore {` instead of `service firebase.storage {`. But I never changed this line so it has been there already when I activated the Storage service. But thanks for the help :)